# Qt C++ Gui lineEdit won`t accept leading Point ( e.c. .8) for input

Tags: c++, windows, qt, decimal-point

Since migrating my Qt 4.8.4-Project to Qt 5.9.2 I to a newly set up PC ( Win10) I have the following problem:

When I try to input a number into a QlineEdit of my GUI I can input something like **1,8**  or **1.8** or even **,8**  . But **.8** won't work. My computer totally ignores the point and writes **8**  . When I read in the value from a file the computer will write **.8** into the lineEdit but then I run into problems when executing strictDoubleValidator::fixup() where he doesn`t replace the **.8** with **0.8** which results in an error.

```
void StrictDoubleValidator::fixup(QString &input) const
{
  if (input.isEmpty())
       return;

   input.replace(",",".");
   if (input.at(0) == '.')
       input.push_front('0');
   if (input.at(input.length()-1) == '.')
       input.push_back('0');
}
```

Comment: Can you please post complete minimal example. Thank you!